# Code refactoring: two but not all the derived classes of a base class have an identical override method

Tags: oop, design-patterns

In C#, a class `B` serves as the only base class of three classes `C`, `D` and `E`.

`B` has a `virtual` method, which is overridden in `C`, `D` and `E`. `C` and `D` have the same implementation of the override method, different from the one in `E`.

`C` and `D` don't have other things in common.

How can I remove code duplicate between `C` and `D`?

Two ways that I am considering are:

1. create a new class `F` derived from `B` and make `C` and `D` derived from `F` instead of `B`. Move the common override method in `C` and `D` to `F`. I think it is overkill, since `C` and `D` don't have other things in common.
2. create a new method in `B`, named differently from the virtual method, and implemented  identically to the common override methods in `C` and `D`. Then change the implementations of the common override methods in `C` and `D`, to just a call the new method in `B`. Is this an elegant solution? Is it some design pattern or Object-Oriented trick?

Thanks.

I don't add C# as a tag, because I think the question is not C# specific, but general to all object oriented languages.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).The idea is to prefer composition over inheritance since inheritance can result in a deep hierarchy and usually the wrong way of code reuse.

Java code:

```
class B {}

class C extends B {
    Behaviour1 b1;
}

class D extends B {
    Behaviour1 b1;
}

class E extends B {
    Behaviour2 b2;
}

class Behaviour1 extends Behavior {}

class Behaviour2 extends Behavior {}
```

You may still utilize inheritance for polymorphic behavior.